# HttpClient ReadAsync never returns

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've randomly issue with my code. I've list of 10 000 urls for testing and randomly it never finished, message "FINISH" isn't printed without any error/exception. I'm fighting with this issue 2 days without solution, any suggest?

Short code to reporduce the problem:
urlist for testing https://www.dropbox.com/s/0x6w1ej0fuxedw9/url.txt

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProblemApp
{
    static class AsyncForEach
    {
        public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(
                from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
                select Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    using (partition)
                        while (partition.MoveNext())
                            await body(partition.Current);
                }));
        }
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Load += OnLoad;
        }

        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Go();
        }

        private async Task<bool> Open(string openurl)
        {

            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(openurl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) return false;

            try
            {
                var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(openurl)))
                    {
                        using (
                            HttpResponseMessage response =
                                await
                                    httpClient.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                                        timeout.Token).ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            if (response != null &&
                                (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                                 response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound))
                            {
                                using (
                                    Stream responseStream =
                                        await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                                {
                                    int read;
                                    int offset = 0;
                                    var rawResponse = new byte[8192];
                                    while (
                                        (read =
                                            await
                                                responseStream.ReadAsync(rawResponse, 0, 8192, timeout.Token)
                                                    .ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
                                    {
                                        offset += read;

                                        if (offset > 1024000)
                                        {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
            //    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
             //   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return true;
        }


        private async void Go()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("url.txt");

            await
                lines.ForEachAsync(500,
                    async line =>
                    {
                        bool result = await Open(line).ConfigureAwait(false); 
                    });

            Console.WriteLine("FINISH");
        }

    }

}
```

ForEachAsync from last example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx

With `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` program is working OK

Comment: Format the code please.

Comment: What is `ForEachAsync()`? Do you ever you use `Wait()` or `Result` in your code? Could you provide [small, but complete](http://sscce.org/) sample code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx last example. I provided code with have isssue. I don't use - 99% of my code is presented in question. The only WaitAll is in ForEachAsync

Comment: @ekapek My point is, it's hard for us to help you if we can't execute your code. That's why I asked for a complete (but short!) sample.

Comment: Does your program hang when reading same urls?

Comment: Program is responding, but it nevers print "FINISHED"

Comment: I can't reproduce this. By writing a message to the console before returning, I can see that Open runs OK, handling timeouts and wrong addresses. I stoped the run after a minute, around url #3000.

Comment: It can't be reproduced without waiting for the FINISH message - the problem is that FINISH never happend

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with fewer URLs? I'd rather not wait for all 10,000 - especially as there are lots of errors...

Comment: I have spplited the list to 2000 parts and run every part alone - program print FINISH for every part, but when I join them to one 10000 it doesn't finish. I'm still trying to reproduce the problem with fewer url but it's hard because somteimes it' finish within 5 minutes and another time it doesn't within 1 hour:(

Comment: I've set up 800 url list and partitionCount to 200 and problem is reproduced